# GitHub - Jenkins -Pvt Repo - Integration

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZXsP.png)

I tried by googling but not go out of it, pleases help me out of i.e., I had added ssh key in git hub and private key in Jenkins as well as in GitHub and in Authorized key and also tried know host file

Answer (score 0):

**Verify SSH Key Permissions:**

Ensure that the SSH private key file (id_rsa) on the Jenkins server has the correct permissions set. The file should only be readable by the Jenkins user. You can set the appropriate permissions with the following command:

> chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

---

**Test SSH Connection Manually:**

On the Jenkins server, try running the following command to see if you can manually establish an SSH connection to GitHub:

> ssh -T git@github.com

If this works, you should see a message like "Hi username! You've successfully authenticated..." If it doesn't work, carefully review any error messages to identify the issue.

---

**Using HTTPS URL for Git:**

Instead of using SSH URLs (git@github.com:user/repo.git), you can try using HTTPS URLs (https://github.com/user/repo.git) for your Git repository in the Jenkins pipeline.